# about ThreadPoolExecutor member variable

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

With my poor english to read DevelopDoc is difficult
When i read `ThreadPoolExecutor` on line 377

```
    private final AtomicInteger ctl = new AtomicInteger(ctlOf(RUNNING, 0));
```

what the whole word about ctl.

```
 *   The main pool control state, ctl, is an atomic integer packing two   
 *   conceptual fields
 *   workerCount, indicating the effective number of threads
 *   runState,    indicating whether running, shutting down etc
```

I guess the answer is 'control state***??'
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: It's just the name of the variable.

Comment: ctl is not a abbr.?
@algrid

Comment: ctl is not a abbr.?@MauricePerry

Comment: It's short for "control".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen in the comment of the variable `ctl`, it is used for two things:

1. record the effective number of threads in the thread pool;
2. record the state of the thread pool;

By track this variable using `ctrl + k` in eclipse, I found it contains some bit operation, so it will take some time to understand the algorithm inside, which you can find some source analyze online.

Guess you are Chinese, there is a [source analyze](http://www.cnblogs.com/killbug/p/4287166.html) about `ThreadPoolExecutor` wrote in Chinese.